# Python chi square goodness of fit test to get the best distribution

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

Given a set of data values, I'm trying to get the best theoretical distribution that describes the data well. I came up with the following python code after days of research.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
import math
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fit_to_all_distributions(data):
    dist_names = ['fatiguelife', 'invgauss', 'johnsonsu', 'johnsonsb', 'lognorm', 'norminvgauss', 'powerlognorm', 'exponweib','genextreme', 'pareto']

    params = {}
    for dist_name in dist_names:
        try:
            dist = getattr(st, dist_name)
            param = dist.fit(data)

            params[dist_name] = param
        except Exception:
            print("Error occurred in fitting")
            params[dist_name] = "Error"

    return params 


def get_best_distribution_using_chisquared_test(data, params):

    histo, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, bins='auto', normed=False)
    number_of_bins = len(bin_edges) - 1
    observed_values = histo

    dist_names = ['fatiguelife', 'invgauss', 'johnsonsu', 'johnsonsb', 'lognorm', 'norminvgauss', 'powerlognorm', 'exponweib','genextreme', 'pareto']

    dist_results = []

    for dist_name in dist_names:

        param = params[dist_name]
        if (param != "Error"):
            # Applying the SSE test
            arg = param[:-2]
            loc = param[-2]
            scale = param[-1]
            cdf = getattr(st, dist_name).cdf(bin_edges, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
            expected_values = len(data) * np.diff(cdf)
            c , p = st.chisquare(observed_values, expected_values, ddof=number_of_bins-len(param))
            dist_results.append([dist_name, c, p])


    # select the best fitted distribution
    best_dist, best_c, best_p = None, sys.maxsize, 0

    for item in dist_results:
        name = item[0]
        c = item[1]
        p = item[2]
        if (not math.isnan(c)):
            if (c < best_c):
                best_c = c
                best_dist = name
                best_p = p

    # print the name of the best fit and its p value

    print("Best fitting distribution: " + str(best_dist))
    print("Best c value: " + str(best_c))
    print("Best p value: " + str(best_p))
    print("Parameters for the best fit: " + str(params[best_dist]))

    return best_dist, best_c, params[best_dist], dist_results
```

Then I test this code by,

```
a, m = 3., 2.
values = (np.random.pareto(a, 1000) + 1) * m
data = pd.Series(values)
params = fit_to_all_distributions(data)
best_dist_chi, best_chi, params_chi, dist_results_chi = get_best_distribution_using_chisquared_test(values, params)
```

Since the data points are generated using Pareto distribution, it should return pareto as the best fitting distribution with a sufficiently large p value (p>0.05).

But this is what I get as output.

```
Best fitting distribution: genextreme
Best c value: 106.46087793622216
Best p value: 7.626303538461713e-24
Parameters for the best fit: (-0.7664124294696955, 2.3217378846757164, 0.3711562696710188)
```

Is there anything wrong with my implementation of Chi Squared goodness of fit test?

Comment: what is `st` in your code?

Comment: scipy.stats module

Comment: The parameter passed to cdf function can be simplified to cdf(bin_edges, *param), just like the case for other scipy stats functions ppf, pdf, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python chi square goodness of fit test (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) mentions that "“Delta degrees of freedom”: adjustment to the degrees of freedom for the p-value. The p-value is computed using a chi-squared distribution with k - 1 - ddof degrees of freedom, where k is the number of observed frequencies. The default value of ddof is 0."

Hence your code should be corrected as follows.

```
c , p = st.chisquare(observed_values, expected_values, ddof=len(param))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Pareto function you are using to draw the random number is not the same as the one you are using to fit the data.

The first one is from [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.pareto.html) and they state

> Draw samples from a Pareto II or Lomax distribution with specified
>   shape.
>
> The Lomax or Pareto II distribution is a shifted Pareto distribution.
>   The classical Pareto distribution can be obtained from the Lomax
>   distribution by adding 1 and multiplying by the scale parameter m.

The [pareto function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pareto.html#scipy.stats.pareto) you use to fit is the one from Scipy and I guess they use a different definition:

> The probability density above is defined in the “standardized” form.
>   To shift and/or scale the distribution use the loc and scale
>   parameters.

Comment: If I use the same pareto distributions as follows, 

    b = 2.62
    values = st.pareto.rvs(b, size=1000)

it shows a very small p value. Is there anything wrong with my implementation of chi sqaured test?

Comment: From simple to complex :) Please write a very simple example using a normal distribution and calculate its chi2 as you do in your example. Then modify your code to draw the numbers from a normal distribution and see if it works then.